# Problema em condição para manipular string

Tags: c, string, criptografia, condição

Era para ele funcionar apenas com as letra minúsculas e quando chegasse em símbolos não alterasse, porem eles estão sendo alterados. Qual o problema?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
char texto[100];
int i = 0,j = 0,con,tam;
printf("texto\n");
gets(texto);
fflush(stdin);
printf("constante\n");
scanf("%d",&con);
tam = strlen(texto);
char cesar[tam];
for(i = 0; i<tam; i++)
{
    if(texto[i] >= 'a' || texto[i]<= 'z')
        cesar[i] = ( (texto[i] - 97 + con)%26 + 97);
    else
        cesar[i] = texto[i];

    printf("%c",cesar[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Podes usar a função [`toupper()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.2.2) (protótipo em `<ctype.h>`) que, bem configurada, converte `'ç'` em `'Ç'` por exemplo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

O problema é a condição que não pode ser OU, deve ser E, do jeito que estava a condição seria sempre verdadeira.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char texto[100];
    int i = 0, con = 0, tam;
    printf("texto\n");
    fgets(texto, 100, stdin);
    printf("constante\n");
    scanf("%d", &con);
    tam = strlen(texto);
    char cesar[tam];
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        if(texto[i] >= 'a' && texto[i] <= 'z')
            cesar[i] = ((texto[i] - 97 + con) % 26 + 97);
        else
            cesar[i] = texto[i];
    
        printf("%c", cesar[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uR4oue). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tzoapvll-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Cesar.c).

Fiz outras melhorias importantes. Mas existem mais algumas que poderiam ser feitas.